# Making an asynchronous API using Task.Run

Tags: api, asynchronous, async-await

Is there anything (anti-pattern) that should prevent me from making an async version of an API call like this?

```
public IItem GetItem(int id)
{
    var result = SomeLengthyServiceCall(id);
    return result;
}

public async Task<IItem> GetItemAsync(int id)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => this.GetItem(id));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is an anti-pattern; see Stephen Toub's excellent blog post on [asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx).

In short, only naturally-asynchronous methods should have asynchronous APIs.